# send a POST request with a file collected from a POST request?

Tags: python, rest, flask

**collect file**

```
parser.add_argument("file", type=werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage, location='files', required=False, help="track file (mp3, mp4, etc)")

ClientInformation._fileFormData = args["file"]
```

###### collect file from POST request . Proof:

```
(Pdb) print(ClientInformation._fileFormData)
<FileStorage: 'Moxie Raia - Could You Be Love (feat. Buddy).mp3' ('audio/mpeg')>
```

---

**uploading collected file**

previously, when uploading file from the desktop, this worked:

```
file = {"file": (track_name, open(track_directory + track_name, 'rb'))}
response = requests.post(url=url, params=payload, headers=headers, files=file)
```

but now that I'm taking the file from a post request, how do i send it?

this doesn't work:

```
file = {"file": (file_upload.__dict__["filename"],file_upload,'rb')}

E       ValueError: read of closed file
```

---

I don't know what method to use from these, that is equivalent to opening the file:

```
file_upload.__bool__             file_upload.__eq__               file_upload.__hash__             file_upload.__module__           file_upload.__repr__             file_upload._parse_content_type  file_upload.mimetype
    file_upload.__class__            file_upload.__format__           file_upload.__init__             file_upload.__ne__               file_upload.__setattr__          file_upload.close                file_upload.mimetype_params
    file_upload.__delattr__          file_upload.__ge__               file_upload.__init_subclass__    file_upload.__new__              file_upload.__sizeof__           file_upload.content_length       file_upload.name
    file_upload.__dict__             file_upload.__getattr__          file_upload.__iter__             file_upload.__nonzero__          file_upload.__str__              file_upload.content_type         file_upload.save
    file_upload.__dir__              file_upload.__getattribute__     file_upload.__le__               file_upload.__reduce__           file_upload.__subclasshook__     file_upload.filename             file_upload.stream
    file_upload.__doc__              file_upload.__gt__               file_upload.__lt__               file_upload.__reduce_ex__        file_upload.__weakref__          file_upload.headers
```

Comment: The file is already opened.  Have you checked the documentation for the Flask FileStorage class at all?  That's why they write it.  You can use the `read()` method to read the file data.

Comment: yes, I didn't get to this point by accident. I forgot to mention that I'm trying to access the file in a different module. I've been trying different solutions to error:ValueError (read of closed file) such as :     file = {"file": (file_upload.filename,file_upload.stream.read())} but cannot get there yet

Comment: how do you get it in other module ? Maybe it closes it in other module and then it can't work - and this may need changes in module, not here.

Comment: @furas I saved the file to the class, ClientInformation . The "proof" is that it is saved and imported into the other module. I tried other approaches using: stream, read, BufferedReader and shared my code here in post and comments: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/o5ndo2/flask_open_file_from_filestorage_error_read_of/ 

----------
got closer but no luck

Comment: better show full code on Stackoverflow or put it on GitHub and add link to full code. As for me your `proof` doesn't proof that it works correctly. If it doesn't work with other methods then file is closed and you have something wrong in module